# How to draw a CanvasRenderingContext2D data into createjs.Bitmap?

Tags: javascript, canvas, bitmap, createjs, animate-cc

I've drowe a dom element into a canvas. 
After cropping the whitespace off of this canvas I'd like to import this into my createjs canvas and animate it there.

I've tried a million things, but nothing worked.

This was my latest trial:

```
function drawBitmap(context)
{
    var container = new cjs.Container();
    stage.addChild(container);

    this.bm = new cjs.Bitmap(context);
    container.addChild(this.bm);
    stage.update();
}
```

Could you help me out with this?

Comment: What is "context"? You can use a canvas element as a source, but not a Canvas rendering context.